# ESRI ST_Geometry struct parse in java

Tags: esri-geodatabase, java, oracle-dbms, st-geometry

I am trying to read and parse the ESRI ST_Geometry which is an oracle user defined type in java manually, and I follow this [instructions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002n0000006m000000), and it said that:

> .... Points: Contains the byte stream of the point coordinates that
>   define the geometry

Now even I read the points(Blob in databse) to `byte[]`, I have no idea how to transfer them to the coordinates.

Is this possible?

---

We have other data in the database which is not produced by ESRI product, if we use ESRI java SDE to access the Spatial data, and get other data from database, I think this is not a good idea. So we use Arcgis SDE to push the spatial data to the database, and try to access the data through jdbc.

And why I do not use the `st_astext` function to get the data is that we are using Hibernate in the application, and I am creating a custom `Dialect` to register the `St_Geometry` column type and read/write the struct. That's why I have to parse the data manually.

And I am inspired by the Hibernate Spatial project, which make the `SDGeometry` column type mappable.

Comment: Why? Wouldn't it be easier to use Esri to access the objects and then get the GeometryCollection/PointCollection from these? If you've got SDE why not use it?

Comment: I would also ask "Why?" and would point out the ability to query via Well-Known Text and Well-Known Binary formats.

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: I am thinking you've made a rod for your own back imposing this restriction on yourself. You're not the only one who has non-spatial data in Oracle... if you're concerned about the access and integrity of these other tables then consider database permissions - it's one thing that Oracle is very good at; if you set them right SDE will not even be able to 'see' the tables its not supposed to.

Comment: Maybe I have not made me clear enough. I do not worry the other data accessed by the SDE user. I mean that I do not want to access spatial data using ESRI java sdk and access no-spatial data by jdbc, I want to use the union solultion(jdbc)  to access all of them

Comment: Use ST_AsText and digest as WKT. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ST_Geometry_generated_from_well_known_text_and_well_known_binary_data/002n0000006n000000/ or change your database to use OGC WKB geometry storage... much easier to read/interpret.

Comment: If you write *one* WKT or WKB integration, you can support *any* WKT or WKB implementation. From the flip side, the Esri spatially aware query tools also support non-spatial column types, so there would be no reason to use multiple SDKs.